# Filling report from bottom to top

Tags: jasper-reports

There is possibility to change way of filling report in details band? Details band is repeated from top to bottom but I want to details band repeated from bottom to top

Comment: I think the answer will be: No. And what is a reason?

Comment: order by desc in query. profit :)
+ Alex K question

Comment: I need to display list rotated left 90 degree. I think I can do that by creating subreport which is filled horizontally which in details band will be text field rotated left 90 degree. So if I could filled subreport details band from bottom to top I could achieve the goal :)